# Generating Random UNIQUE and converting to binary in C

Tags: c, random, binary

I have implemented a basic program which generates 10 random and  unique numbers from 1 to 10 as shown below. I have added an extra part in which I want the binary representation for each unique and random number. My program looks like this.

```
   int value=1, loop, loop1, get=0, x, arr[10], array[20], count, i =0, y;
   srand(time(NULL));

for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for (count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
        array[count] = rand() % 10 + 1;     //generate random number between 1 to 10 and put in array
    }
    while (i < 10) {
        int r = rand() % 10 + 1;    // declaring int r 

        for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
        {
            if (array[x] == r) {    //if integer in array x is equal to the random number generated
                break;              //break
            }
        }
        if (x == i) {           //if x is equal to i then   
            array[i++] = r;         //random number is placed in array[10]
        }
    }
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        printf("unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
        array[y] = value;

        for (loop = 0; loop < 1000; loop++)
        {
            if (value <= 1) { arr[loop] = 1; break; }       //if value is 1 after dividing put 1 in array
            if (value % 2 == 0) arr[loop] = 0;
            else arr[loop] = 1;

            value = value / 2;
        }
        for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--)
            printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
        printf("\n");
    }   
   }
```

My problem is that The binary value for each random unique number is being given as 1. In this program it is seen that I initialised `value=1` and this can be the source for my error, however when I remove this I get an error stating that the local variable is uninitialised.

The first part of my program which generates the unique numbers is working fine, however the second part where I am converting to binary is not.

**EDIT:** I tested The second part of my program and it works well on it's own. The problem must be the way I am combining the two programs together.

Comment: Store and compare, then accept the newly generated random number.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. @StephanLechner, what a stupid mistake I must have overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement `array[y] = value` overrides the previously generated random values with constant `1`.write

```
  value = array[y];
```

Comment: Glad you posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the commented code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//function to check unique random number 
int check(int array[],int count,int val)
{
    int i=0;
    for( ;i<count ;++i )
    {
        if (array[i]==val)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int value,loop, loop1, get, x, arr[10];
    int oldRandoms[10]; // array to preserve old random values

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        do // do while to get only unique random number 
        {
            get = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }while(check(oldRandoms,x,get));
        oldRandoms[x]=get; // backup the number 

        printf("random number is %d \n", get);
        value = get;

        for (loop = 0; loop < 1000; loop++)
        {
            if (value <= 1) { arr[loop] = 1; break; }   //if value is 1 after dividing put 1 in array
            if (value % 2 == 0) arr[loop] = 0;
            else arr[loop] = 1;

            value = value / 2;
        }
        for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--)
            printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your insight on this matter. I will test the solution out.

Comment: This works well, thanks for giving another perspective to my problem. I will +1 this as soon as I reach 15 rep.